# Calculate cumulative Runtime by group in SQL server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In SQL Server, I have maintained following details.

| S.No | Year | Component1 | Total Run years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2011 | AAA | 3 |
| 2 | 2011 | BBB | 5 |
| 3 | 2011 | CCC | 7 |
| 4 | 2012 | AAA | 6 |
| 5 | 2012 | BBB | 2 |
| 6 | 2012 | CCC | 4 |
| 7 | 2013 | AAA | 3 |
| 8 | 2013 | BBB | 2 |
| 9 | 2013 | CCC | 5 |

I would like to calculate Cumulative **Total Run years** BY Year and Component1 group

Required result like this,

| Year | Component1 | Total Run years |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | AAA | 3 |
| 2011 | BBB | 5 |
| 2011 | CCC | 7 |
| 2012 | AAA | 9 |
| 2012 | BBB | 7 |
| 2012 | CCC | 11 |
| 2013 | AAA | 12 |
| 2013 | BBB | 9 |
| 2013 | CCC | 16 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should easily solve your problem.

```
SELECT
Year,
Component1,
Total Run years,
SUM(Total Run years) OVER (PARTITION BY Component1 ORDER BY Year ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 'CUMULATIVE_TOTAL'
FROM table
GROUP BY Year, Component1, Total Run years
ORDER BY Year, Component1
```

See here https://stevestedman.com/2013/04/rows-and-range-preceding-and-following/ for more examples using ROWS, PRECEDING, FOLLOWING.